# Combining two lists which contain strings and None type data

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists of data of the following form:

```py
List1 = ['String1', None, None]
List2 = [None, 'String2', None]
```

I want to combine these lists to give the following:

```
List3 = ['String1', 'String2', None]
```

The current code I have is as follows based on other stack overflow questions:

```
''.join(filter(None, (df.iloc[0,:], df.iloc[1,:])))
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Do you want all different values that are existing in the list?
Does the order of elements is relevant?

Comment: Are these lists values in a dataframe? Or are these literal lists?

Comment: What if element zero (for example) was a string in both lists? What are the rules here?

Answer (score 2):

They're just lists and not dataframes, so toss out the current code. You can get List3 as follows:

```
List3 = [(x if type(x) == str else List2[i]) for i,x in enumerate(List1)]
```

Then each element of List3 will be the element at the same index of List1 if that element is a string, and the corresponding element of List2 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Since None works well with logical operators, you could also try this:

```
List3 = list(map(lambda x, y: x or y, List1, List2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
[e1 or e2 for e1,e2 in zip(List1, List2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to check for `type`. Use the fact that `None` evaluates to `False` in a boolean context.

```
List1 = ['String1', None, None]
List2 = [None, 'String2', None]

List3 = [List1[i] or List2[i] for i in range(len(List1))]
print(List3)
# ['String1', 'String2', None]
```